# Getting issue while copying remote computer

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement to copy files from local computer to remote machines,

using the below command but its not working, please help

```cs
$Stat = $null
$Source = "C:\Temp\test\"
$Destination = "C:\temp\"

$Stat = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
    Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Destination
} -Credential $user
```

Error:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Comment: `-Force -PassThru -Verbose` try adding this at the of of $Destination

Comment: @WojtekT What is that supposed to change about the fact that `$Source` is empty inside the scriptblock (as the error message clearly states)?

Comment: I'm not sure thats the best duplicate to link to. Was there not one that used `Invoke-Command`?

Comment: Still its not working, please suggest how to copy from local computer to Remote computer with Credentials (FYI: version of powershell is 3.0 in my system, because of this not able to use -ToSession option)
I tried with  readallbytes and writeallbytes, it is very slow for 35 MB file (took almost 10 mins+)
Please suggest the command to copy file to remote with credential

Comment: That's an entirely different question. For copying from the local to a remote computer you need access to a file share. Use `New-PSDrive` to map a shared folder of the remote host on the local computer, then `Copy-Item` the file(s) to the mapped drive.

Comment: @MarkWragg That's the best one I had in my bookmarks. ;) I added another link to a question explicitly about `Invoke-Command`.